# How to remove a panel from my desktop?

Tags: kubuntu, display, 18.10, plasma

I'm running Kubuntu 18.10 KDE Plasma 5.13.5, added a new Kubuntu panel to the top. Removed the panel via context menu, but part of panel stuck on top of my desktop. How to remove it? Can't right click it.
[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click onto the Desktop, select `Configure Desktop`, go to `Tweaks` and uncheck the `Show the desktop toolbox` radio button.